# Android volley gridview onclick item index doesnt start with 0

Tags: java, android, android-volley, indexoutofboundsexception, android-gridview

I am using a custom gridview adapter to show images with volley singleton. The gridview showing the images are fine, its just that when I click the FIRST image it  crashes instantly.

I have tried using URLS[i-6] but it doesnt return the right thing. There are 6 images, somehow the index of the first image is 6 thus causing the out of bound exception. I tried changing bits here and there that might cause the index starting at 6 but no result at all..

The error:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
                  at com.example.user.assignmentfourtwo.MainActivity$1$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:80)
```

Which is this line:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, URLS[i].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 250;
private final String KEY = "IMAGE";
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
private static final String URLS[] = {
    "http://10.0.2.2/Android%20A4_1/germany.png",
    "http://10.0.2.2/Android%20A4_1/indonesia.png",
    "http://10.0.2.2/Android%20A4_1/japan.png",
    "http://10.0.2.2/Android%20A4_1/sarawak.png",
    "http://10.0.2.2/Android%20A4_1/singapore.png",
    "http://10.0.2.2/Android%20A4_1/switzerland.png",
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    for(int i = 0; i<URLS.length; i++) {
        LoadingImages(URLS[i]);
    }
}

private void LoadingImages(String url) {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
            Bitmap image = response.getBitmap();
            Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE);
            bitmaps.add(thumbnail);

            GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);


            final ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, bitmaps);
            gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);


            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, URLS[i].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
//                        intent.putExtra(KEY, URLS[i]);
//                        startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Do you even error?", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}

MySingleton.java:

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton instance;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private static Context context;

private MySingleton(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>(6);
        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            Bitmap bmp = cache.get(url);
            if (bmp == null) {
                System.out.println("Not in cache");
            } else {
                System.out.println("In cache");
            }

            return bmp;
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            System.out.println("Put in cache");
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return imageLoader;
}
```

}

ImageAdapter.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
private final String KEY = "IMAGE";

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bitmaps.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return bitmaps.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    if (view == null) {
      final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
      view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.griditems, null);
      MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
      view.setTag(myViewHolder);
    }
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder)view.getTag();
    myViewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(i));

    return view;
}

public class MyViewHolder {
   public ImageView img;

   public MyViewHolder(View view) {
       img = view.findViewById(R.id.image1);

   }


}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a header on your list view?

Comment: Do you mean the gridview in my XML folder?

Comment: Yes, that is, if you manage to set a header on a ListView (I haven't tried for GridView), it counts the header as part of the list so you might have to do some offset when you want to access the actual items.